# reading a pixel from an overlapped window (windows xp)

Tags: winapi, windows-xp

Vista and Win7 use DWM, thus, I can read any pixel from any top-level window, no problems.
However, in XP, if the window is overlapped (by another top-level window), bye bye - can't read anything.

So, the option is - use WM_PRINT, which kinda' sucks, because I need to scrape the screen for probably 10 windows, every 100ms or so - not cool.

Is there any other way of reading a pixel except for GetPixel, or another workaround for this?

Best,
John

Comment: I assume that you actually mean **layered** windows (those with the `WS_EX_LAYERED` extended style)? You can read pixels from overlapped windows (those with the `WS_OVERLAPPED` style) just fine on all versions of Windows.

Comment: I meant, a top-level window which has at least a part that is overlapped by another top-level window. In this case, you can't read the pixels from it (using GetPixel).

Comment: Ah, no. That pixel isn't actually there on the screen. `WM_PRINT` is the only workaround—only that window knows what color it's supposed to draw there. Why do you need to poll for the color of a specific pixel every 100 ms?

Comment: For http://speak-poker.com Basically i need to know if buttons are shown on each poker table - the only way to do this is by screen scraping.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to support a ten your old operating system.  Moore's law has solved the memory problem since then.  If you *really* want to support it then you'll have to do this a different way.  Not entirely a bad idea, Aero is optional and may be off.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I think the problem is worth solving differently even if you completely dropped support for Win XP. Lots of people disable Aero and that's still a supported configuration.

Comment: Basically i'm trying to see if there's a decently simple way to do this. If not, I might not support WinXP altogether.

Comment: @cody : are you telling me on Vista/7 if Aero is dropped, then i can't access the pixels if the window is overlapped?

Comment: @John: Yes. What's allowing you to do this on Vista/7 is DWM, as your question correctly points out. DWM is disabled when you disable the Aero theme and revert to the Classic theme. Of course, it sounds like this may be just a one-off project for your personal use. If that's the case, you can afford to make some concessions that a commercial product couldn't. Personally, I run with the Aero theme off, and I know lots of other techies that do. But if you like Aero and have it on, then there's little reason to hassle over supporting Classic in a personal app. Same with dropping XP support.

Comment: @cody: it's not for personal use. And about Aero: got it, thanks!